# How to regenerate Azure AppsServices Auth Signing Key (WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

Lets say my WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY was compromised.

Is there a way to generate a new one?

I tried going to kudu, opening the console and typing set WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY = new key. It works but as soon as the site is restarted it goes back to the original value.

Edit:

I also tried with:

```
app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler =  config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
```

This seems to work (don't know if it is the corret way of doing it). But for Facebook authentication  (the endpoint /.auth/login/facebook) it does not use my custom key or valid audience or anything, it uses the defaults and i can't change them. This seems like a bug in Azure maybe which is very annoying and makes the whole thing pretty useless if it can't be changed.

Thanks

Comment: To confirm, which platform you are using in your Azure Mobile App, C# or Node.js?

Comment: I am using the C# platform.

Comment: Hi @joaozinhodascouves, do you have any update?

Answer (score 2):

According your description, you have:

> tried going to kudo, opening the console and typing set WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY = new key

But have you replaced the configuration setting in your portal? Please try to change the `WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY` setting in your Azure Mobile Apps portal.

[image]

Comment: That does not work because now AppServices reads the key from an Environment Variable.

Comment: No, that's a special setting that will tell App Service to use that signing key instead. * Note: The signing key can't be any string, it needs to be a SHA-256 hashed string.